# Jersey matches regex pattern before the method type

Tags: regex, jersey, jax-rs

Is it possible to define 2 methods in `Jersey` with same regex but different type? (`GET`, `PUT` ..):

```
@GET
@Path("{key: .+}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response root(String key) {
}

@PUT
@Path("{key: .+}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response publish(String key, FormDataMultiPart data) {
}
```

The first method should only reply for the key (with or without slashes)

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost/key
Jersey respond with 200 OK since it went to the GET method

curl -X GET "http://localhost/key/
Jersey respond with 200 OK since it went to the GET method

curl -X PUT -T file.txt "http://localhost/key
Jersey respond with 200 OK since it went to the PUT method

curl -X PUT -T file.txt "http://localhost/key/
Jersey respond with 200 OK since it went to the PUT method

curl -X PUT -T file.txt "http://localhost/key/folder/folder
Jersey respond with 405 Method Not Found since it went to the GET method
instead of the PUT (the get only respond to 1 folder level which is the 'key'
but i expected that jersey will go directly to the PUT since it suppose to check for the method type before the regex matching
```

Why the last one doesn't work? it seems Jersey first looks for regex even though it's a `PUT` request.

Comment: You need to provide some more information.  What exactly are you sending, how are you sending it, and what does Jersey do when you send it?  Any stack traces would also be useful.

Comment: I've updated my question with a simpler demonstration

Comment: If you take the `@Consumes` out, what happens with that last `curl`?

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: How about taking out the `@Consumes` and the `FormDataMultiPart data` parameter? It seems the lack of `-T file` in the `curl` command has effects.

Comment: When you supply no file, it has no `data` parameter, thus matching to the `@GET` method.

Answer (score 0):

You say "Jersey respond with 405 Method Not Found since it went to the GET method instead of the PUT" but a 405 means that it didn't go to any method.  Try changing your PUT method to:

```
@PUT
@Path("{key: .+}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response publish(String key) {
}
```

And that should work.  You then need to ensure that you provide the correct data as part of your CURL request to ensure that it matches the `@Consumes` annotation when you put it back in to the request.

Comment: Oops sorry my last example is missing the -T, what i wanted to elaborate is that the first PUT command works fine, it seems the only difference is the path (/key works but /key/folder/folder doesn't)